# Is it possible to extend a tourist Schengen visa (12 more days)?

Tags: visas, schengen, visa-extensions

My daughter applied at the Italian Consulate in Philadelphia, and they gave her two entries for 20 days (we thought it was for 20 days each entry). She was in Italy 12 days, then went to England for 1 week and flew to Venice to take a 10-day cruise. She couldn't make it because they said she has only 8 remaining days, but she still has a land tour already paid this week.

What can she do? Can she extend the Schengen visa for 12 more days? Right now, she is in Madrid, but next week she has to fly from Barcelona to Paris to start with the tour. What would happen if she decides to take the tour with the expired visa? She is a US permanent resident.

Answer (score 7):

There is no easy way to extend a Schengen visa. Article 33 of the [Schengen Visa code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810&from=EN) only allows an extension if you cannot leave the Schengen area (*force majeure*) or you can provide “proof of serious personal reasons”. Otherwise you have to apply for another visa and you can only do that from your place of residence.

The only solution around that would be a national visitor visa (if the country allows you to apply for it after entering the Schengen area, which is not always the case), see our related [question #1](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26794/is-it-possible-to-extend-my-90-day-short-stay-in-sweden-by-10-or-15-days) or [question #2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26589/how-to-extend-my-stay-in-the-schengen-area-at-the-end-of-my-trip?lq=1).

If she decides to stay anyway, she will mostly risk a fine upon exiting the Schengen area. Having overstayed will also possibly compromise her ability to get a Schengen visa in the future.

Comment: In the other two questions, an extension would have gone over the 90 day limit. This isn't the case here.

Comment: @Gilles Indeed (I certainly do not advocate closing the question!) but the rules still do not allow an extension AFAIK and a national visa (where possible) would be a solution so the links should be of interest.

Comment: @Gilles I tried to clarify that and provide more info.