# Staying in the Schengen Area after the permitted days of entry but before the visa expiry

Tags: schengen, greece, visa-extensions

I was given a Schengen Visa (from Greece) valid from July 17 to August 8, but only 8 days permitted to stay.

My flight is originally July 17-24, but something came up and need to extend the stay until July 28 (additional 4 days).

What do I need to do? Help please!

Comment: The only feasible solution is to apply for another visa Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to extend a tourist Schengen visa (12 more days)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31164/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-tourist-schengen-visa-12-more-days)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.  However, I would like to have a bit of more clarity on the situation.  My first entry will be in Vienna (July 18).  Then taking a bus to Budapest then flying to Naples.  Then Naples to non-schengen area on July 28.  In total that is 11 days, 3 days more than my permitted stay but still within the visa validity.

Comment: If you arrive on the 17th and leave on the 28th that is 12 days, not 11.  You must count every partial day as a full day, including both the day of entry and the day of exit.

Answer (score 5):

The issuing consulate has given you permission to stay in the Schengen area for eight days. To allow some flexibility in flights they have allowed you to arrive on or after 17th July and depart on or before 8th August. So, whatever date you arrive, you **must** leave the area within eight days, or by 8th August, whichever comes first.

In your situation you have two choices: apply for a new visa to cover the additional period, or delay your arrival until 21st July, so that you can depart on 28th July.

Note that the day of arrival and day of departure each count as one day, even if you're only in the area for part of a day.