# Extending Brazilian's citizen stay in Austria while they are in Austria

Tags: schengen, tourist-visas, eu, austria, brazil

A friend of mine from Brazil, currently in Austria (turist visit), wants to extend his stay in the country. He spent 80 of 90 days in Austria and found out today that they cannot apply for the visa here; the application must be made in Brazil or potentially Portugal.

What is the best way for my friends to extend his stay in Austria, ideally without traveling to Brazil/Portugal and coming back?

Comment: Best have them leave the Schengen zone before day 89 is up, see the recent questions about overstays and a legal problems from that.

Comment: Do the answers [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/31164/is-it-possible-to-extend-a-tourist-schengen-visa-12-more-days) apply to your situation fully? I believe they do

Comment: Day 89 to leave one day for a transit through a Schengen country on the way home.