# Long term "visitor visa" for Germany as a non-professional

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, germany, long-stay-visas

I am an Indian citizen currently in France with a long-term "visitor visa", valid for one year. Visitor visa allows me to stay in France for more than 90 days without working, [see for example](http://www.consulfrance-losangeles.org/spip.php?article799).

Is there a similar "visitor visa" for Germany which should allow me to stay in Germany for one year without working provided I have sufficient personal income already?

I know France and Sweden allows "visitor visa" i.e permit to stay in france (or Sweden) for more than 90 days without work. My question is whether Germany does the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the options for a non-EU national who wants to stay in Germany for more than 90 days?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26589/what-are-the-options-for-a-non-eu-national-who-wants-to-stay-in-germany-for-more)

Comment: My question is not a duplicate because I am not trying to renew a short term visa. I am just asking whether Gemany supports long term "visitor visa" without work.

Comment: @BiswarupRay Your question isn't closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, anything beyond the Schengen C visa would be a befristete Aufenthaltserlaubnis (temporary residence permit). There is a list of reasons why such a permit can be granted, but tourism isn't on it.

On the other hand, an Aufenthaltserlaubnis *may* be granted for non-university language studies. I can't say if this would be granted in your case.