# Can I get a Schengen visa if I'm already inside the Schengen area?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am Canadian and I am traveling with the 90/180 days visa. Right now I am in Spain I would like to travel more in Europe, is there a way I could get a Schengen Area Visa even if I am not in Canada to ask for it?

Comment: You may need to leave the Schengen area to do so, but that may not require that you return to Canada.

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26589/what-are-the-options-for-a-non-eu-national-who-wants-to-stay-in-germany-for-more

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26794/what-are-the-options-for-a-non-eu-national-who-wants-to-stay-in-sweden-for-more?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 7):

> is there a way I could get a Schengen Area Visa even if I am not in Canada

Generally speaking nothing stops you from going to e.g. the French consulate in Spain and applying for a visa. Schengen rules don't forbid the issuance of visas from within the Schengen area. However applying for a short-term visa won't allow you to ignore the 90/180 days rule, as the rule applies regardless of how many short-term visas (or [visa-free passports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24087/could-a-citizen-of-two-countries-eligible-for-90-180-schengen-stays-legally-rema)) you have.

The only option to stay for more than 90 days in the Schengen area is to obtain a long-term (category D) visa or residency permit. You can ask about the options of obtaining such a visa on our sister site [Expats StackExchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).